# print out a pointer upto desired length only

Tags: c, string, pointers, segmentation-fault, memcpy

I hava a C function like this ..

```
func(uint8_t *key,uint8_t keylen) {

FILE *fk;
fk=fopen("akey","wb");
fwrite((char *)key,keylen,1,fk);

puts((char *)key); // for testing

fclose(fk);

sprintf(sstring,"... \"%s\" ... ",(char *)key);
        // ...other irrelevant stuff for here
system(sstring);


}
```

I want the key provided as input to be used at the
place marked `\"%s\"` in `sprintf` command

**Input :**

```
  Key=qwerty
```

**Output :**

```
 $cat akey
 qwerty
```

and output of `puts((char *)key)` is -

```
 qwerty�    

 // include newline character as well
```

Suggest me on this , I tried with this (at their respective position in the code)
but getting `segmentation fault`

```
    char *p;
    memcpy(p,(char *)key,keylen);
    puts((char *)p);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the form `%.*s` to print it out:

```
printf("%.*s\n", (int)keylen, (char *)key);
...
sprintf(sstring,"... %.*s ... ", ... (int)keylen, (char *)key ...);
```

Here an extract from the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string) on `printf`:

> The width and precision formatting parameters may be omitted, or they
>   can be a fixed number embedded in the format string, or passed as
>   another function argument when indicated by an asterisk "*" in the
>   format string. For example printf("%*d", 5, 10) will result in "   10"
>   being printed, with a total width of 5 characters, and printf("%.*s",
>   3, "abcdef") will result in "abc" being printed.

**NOTE**: Using an 8-bit type (`uint8_t`) to represent the length limits the length of the string to 255 characters.  Better is to use `size_t`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to null-terminate your string (add a trailing '\0' byte) or use %ns (like "%.5s" for qwerty. Null termination is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

`sprintf` expects a 0-terminated string. That might not be the case in your application. With regard to using memcpy - you need to allocate memory first. Also make sure you check for errors, e.g. whether `fk != NULL`

Memory allocation example:

```
char *p = malloc(keylen + 1);
// check that p != NULL here
memcpy(p,(char *)key,keylen);
p[keylen] = 0;
puts((char *)p);
free(keylen);
```